# Get image from cache in glide

Tags: android-glide

How can I get the image bitmap from cache in glide just like universal image loader?

Here is an Example. In universal image loader we can do this.

String mCache=MemoryCacheUtil.generateKey(uri,getImageSize(imageView));

return mImageLoader.getMemoryCache().get(mCache);

Comment: added code formatting, minor grammar.